# Raspbmc not booting on Pi 2

Tags: raspbmc, pi-2

According to [this](http://makezine.com/2015/02/02/eben-upton-raspberry-pi-2/):

> So from today you should be able to ‘apt-get upgrade’ on an existing
>   Raspbian installation to add an ARMv7 kernel to your distribution. The
>   SD card can then be used — assuming it’s a Micro SD Card — to boot
>   either a first or second generation Pi.

My /etc/apt/sources.list contents:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Ofc, I have done this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Nevertheless, even after I've updated the existing Raspbmc, it won't boot when used in Raspberry Pi 2.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the author of said quote had good intention, his premise (that firmware would be updated with `apt-get upgrade`) was incorrect.

To update the firmware and thus add support for ARMv7 hardware to Raspbian-compatible distribution (which Raspbmc is), user just needs to do the standard procedure for updating firmware -- this:

```
sudo rpi-update
```

The whole tutorial (with know caveats and their workarounds) can be found here: https://www.hifiberry.com/guides/updating-the-linux-kernel/

This is my output from the final command:

```
pi@raspbmc ~ $ sudo -E RPI_UPDATE_UNSUPPORTED=0 rpi-update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7938  100  7938    0     0  13677      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 23837
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** We're running for the first time
 *** Backing up files (this will take a few minutes)
 *** Backing up firmware
 *** Backing up modules 3.12.31
 *** Downloading specific firmware revision (this will take a few minutes)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   168    0   168    0     0    232      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   311
100 43.1M  100 43.1M    0     0   170k      0  0:04:19  0:04:19 --:--:--  217k
 *** Updating firmware
 *** Updating kernel modules
 *** depmod 3.18.5-v7+
 *** depmod 3.18.5+
 *** Updating VideoCore libraries
 *** Using HardFP libraries
 *** Updating SDK
 *** Running ldconfig
 *** Storing current firmware revision
 *** Deleting downloaded files
 *** Syncing changes to disk
 *** If no errors appeared, your firmware was successfully updated to 93cb9a45741681987b207c68b63db7ab72b2a4cf
 *** A reboot is needed to activate the new firmware
```

After the reboot, Raspbmc worked as before on the Pi 1 (which I used to update the firmware, ofc). When i placed the updated Raspbmc to Pi 2, it booted and Kodi worked w/o any problem.

Answer (score -2):

I don't thing Raspbmc is supported on the Pi 2.

You will need to use OSMC instead.

http://www.raspbmc.com/2015/02/raspberry-pi-2-0-and-raspbmcs-last-update/