# Raspberry 2 and Raspbmc not booting

Tags: boot, raspbmc, boot-issues

Got my new Pi 2 and installed Raspbian - works fine.
Same Pi, same SD card with raspbmc: Not booting.
When I plug in the power, I get a red and a green LED for a short time, but then the green one turns off. On the screen I just see that colorful square you see on every boot. 
I've already tried using the python script from http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/os-x-linux-installation/ and dd'ing the raspbmc image from http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ to my SD card. A also downloaded the OpenELEC image and it doesn't boot either.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RaspBMC Pi Version supported: Pi 1 only
http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: Darn I could swear I saw the opposite information somewhere but know that you say that I found it on the raspbmc homepage, too. Thanks. Ok, then I have to get the OSMC installer working... -.-

Comment: UPDATE: There seems to be a workaround, at least if migrating from an old installation: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27395/raspbmc-not-booting-on-pi-2?rq=1 
However since the developer said he's not working on RaspBMC for the Pi 2, this seems sort of dirty.